Android images grayed out under the hamburger menu - Android studio
I'm facing the issue and cannot find a solution for it.
I'm trying to set some images under the hamburger menu but those stays grayed out (png format).
The interesting thing is that if I use the same images under the different xml (main_toolbar.xml) those are working as expected.
I tried with android:iconTint="@null" but this doesn't help.
Code of the xml where images are grayed out:
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:iconTint="@null"
        android:title="Something"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        
        />
    <group android:id="@+id/group_divider">
        <item android:id="@+id/menu_licenses"
            android:icon="@drawable/license3"
            android:title="@string/menu_licenses"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <item android:id="@+id/menu_disclaimer"
            android:icon="@drawable/eula3"
            android:title="@string/menu_disclaimer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <item android:id="@+id/menu_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/about3"
            android:title="@string/menu_about"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </group>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings3"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings" />
</menu>

When I run this, below appears where images are grayed out:
enter image description here
Now, in the xml with code below same image "@mipmap/icon" works great and is shown correctly:
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/center_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:paddingRight="65dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/icon" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>type here

As one can see image at the top is shown correctly:
enter image description here
Does anyone has experience with this? Could someone advise please?
Regards
Tried with android:iconTint="@null"
